# Grunt j with regular expressions

Tags: regex, node.js, sass, gruntjs

```
grunt.config('sass', {
    options: {
      sourceMap: true
    },
    dist: {
      options: {
        outputStyle: 'compact'
      },
      files: {
        '/css/site.css': 'main/scss/site.scss',
        '/css/template.home.css': 'main/scss/templates/home.scss'
        '/css/template.contact.css': 'main/scss/templates/contact.scss'
        '/css/template.something.css': 'main/scss/templates/something.scss'
      }
    }
});
```

is there is any way to handle this part nicely ( Thinking about a pattern but I' not sure about the possibility  )

```
'/css/template.home.css': 'main/scss/templates/home.scss'
'/css/template.contact.css': 'main/scss/templates/contact.scss'
'/css/template.something.css': 'main/scss/templates/something.scss'
```

Comment: "handle this part"?

Comment: Yes @ClasG I want to reduce these three lines to one, because I need to add few other lines too.Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you declare the config as a JS object you could do it like this:

```js
var cfg = {
        options: {
            sourceMap: true
        },
        dist: {
            options: {
                outputStyle: 'compact'
            },
            files: {
                '/css/site.css': 'main/scss/site.scss',
                '/css/template.home.css': 'main/scss/templates/home.scss',
                '/css/template.contact.css': 'main/scss/templates/contact.scss',
                '/css/template.something.css': 'main/scss/templates/something.scss'
            }
        }
    },
    grunt = {
      config: function() {
        document.write('<br/><strong>grunt config set</string><br/>');
      }
    };

    document.write('<br/>"files" before new config:<br/><br/>');

    for (var property in cfg.dist.files) {
        if (cfg.dist.files.hasOwnProperty(property)) {
            document.write(property + ' = ' + cfg.dist.files[property] + '<br/>');
        }
    }

    document.write('<br/>"files" after added config:<br/><br/>');

    cfg.dist.files['/css/what ever...'] = 'the/latest/path';

    for (var property in cfg.dist.files) {
        if (cfg.dist.files.hasOwnProperty(property)) {
            document.write(property + ' = ' + cfg.dist.files[property] + '<br/>');
        }
    }

    grunt.config('sass', cfg);
```

Note the

```
    cfg.dist.files['/css/what ever...'] = 'the/latest/path';
```

That's where the additional config is added.

Comment: Much appreciated !
I don't want to define file names in to any where . I need to include all files following by that pattern to include my configuration.
Something like this 

` '/css/template.%1.css': 'main/scss/templates/$1.scss' `